# R: Function to export currently active R plot to Powerpoint/Word/LibreOffice

Tags: r, ggplot2, export, powerpoint, reporters

Currently I always export my R graphs to Powerpoint in vector format using the excellent `ReporteRs` package, as in

```
library(ReporteRs)
myplot = function() print(qplot(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length, data = iris, color = Species, size = Petal.Width, alpha = I(0.7)))
doc = pptx()
doc = addSlide(doc, slide.layout = "Blank") 
doc = addPlot( doc, myplot, vector.graphic = TRUE, fontname="Arial",
               offx = 0.1*dim(doc)$slide.dim["width"], offy = 0.05*dim(doc)$slide.dim["height"], 
               width = 0.8*dim(doc)$slide.dim["width"], height = 0.9*dim(doc)$slide.dim["height"])
writeDoc( doc, "plot.pptx")
```

[image]

What I find inconvenient in this workflow is that I now have to wrap my plot commands in a function (with `print()` for `lattice` or `ggplot2` plots, or just `return(plot())` for base R plots), and that I don't like having to manually specify the offsets and size (I usually prefer to just get a nearly page filling, centered graph in my slide). I was just wondering if instead it wouldn't be possible to make your plot first (base R plot, `lattice` plot or `ggplot2` plot) and then define a function `export2PPT` that captures the output of your current graphics device as a function and passes it on to `ReporteRs` and `addPlot` to export your plot as Powerpoint (centered & appropriately scaled), in analogy to function `dev.copy2pdf` that works in the same way to export to PDF?

And once we have such a function, perhaps even [modify the `grDevices` source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16317706/redefining-a-function-in-an-r-package) of functions [windows() and savePlot()](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/library/grDevices/R/windows/windows.R) to have an additional command File...Save as Powerpoint if one was using the `windows()` device? Or is this something for the R Core people to do?

Especially for use in the classroom this would be super handy I think, given the dominance of MS Office/LibreOffice.
(as Powerpoint is much easier to edit than PDF, allowing one to easily make small changes in the final layout of R graphs, and vector output is at least as good as PDF, plus transparency is also fully supported - for PDF I find that import in Inkscape is often a bit buggy, unless one uses Adobe Illustrator)

Anybody who would know how to do this?

EDIT: In the meantime I found the solution, and have wrapped export functions to export the currently active R plot to powerpoint in a package on CRAN, see
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/export/index.html and
https://github.com/tomwenseleers/export for demo usage. The package now uses the officer package as a backend, as ReporteRs is deprecated...

Comment: For editing in Inkscape, I'd usually export in .svg. For the second part of your question, are you talking about RGui, RStudio or something else?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out - I was under the impression that .svg did not support transparency/alpha channels, but apparently now it does... Definitely seen cases where svg export also gets screwed up at times though... And still prefer editing in Powerpoint, especially for simple things. Second part of my question was about how one could implement a File...Save As Powerpoint tab using the function below, either in the plot tab of RStudio, or the interactive window you get when you use windows() and then make your plot in that (under Windows)

Comment: I second the suggestion that an "export to Powerpoint" button or a simple-to-use function would be handy. I know many people that are more familiar with Powerpoint than Illustrator, Inkscape etc (and who prefer to make all the fine adjustments in mouse-driven software), and I'm sure this function would see plenty of use.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Just made a new CRAN package `export` that allows one to export an R plot in the currently active graphics device to either Powerpoint or Word (or LibreOffice Impress/Writer) in editable (DrawingML) vector format as a one-liner, with full support for transparency, etc, see
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/export/index.html
and demo at
https://github.com/tomwenseleers/export

For example:

```
install.packages("export")
library(export)
```

Example to export `lattice` plot:

```
library(effects)
fit=lm(prestige ~ type + income*education, data=Prestige)
plot(Effect(c("income", "education"), fit),multiline=T, ci.style="bands")
graph2ppt(file="effect plot.pptx", width=7, height=5)
```

[image]

which after right clicking in PPT on "ungroup" can be seen to be nicely in vector format:

[image]

From Word or PPT these graphs also export perfectly to (vector format) PDF by using File...Save as...PDF, and it is much easier to make minor tweaks to the layout than is possible by editing directly in the PDF.

If the R Core or RStudio people would like to include this functionality please do - would be super handy for use in the classroom I think, given the dominance and widespread use of the Office suite!

Comment: Maybe it's because this is an old post, but I'm still struggling with that. I tried your solutions and I get Error in addPlot.docx(doc, myplot, vector.graphic = vector.graphic, fontname = fontname,  : 
  argument 4 matches multiple formal arguments

Comment: @TomWenseleers is it possible to submit your package to a CRAN repository ? You probably would have to change the name as export is maybe a reserved name, to like tomexport or TWexport. or Qwickexport. I think it would be beneficial for those who can not install from github (like me..hey hey)

Comment: Just to let you all know that these export functions are now out on CRAN, see https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/export/index.html

Comment: Package ‘export’ was removed from the CRAN repository.

Comment: @dpel Export is back up on CRAN now: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/export/index.html

Answer (score 1):

You can try the eoffice package which also available in CRAN.