# Export several plots from R into ppt

Tags: r, plot, powerpoint

I found a function here to create a ppt with a slide for a plot created in R.
Here is the link to that function: [R: Function to export currently active R plot to Powerpoint/Word/LibreOffice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31212659/r-function-to-export-currently-active-r-plot-to-powerpoint-word-libreoffice)

I would like my program to add several slide (containing one plot each).

I currently use : `export2ppt(file="plot.pptx")`
But I can't figure out how I add a second plot to the same file .

Comment: `addPlot(` which used in your fucntion . added new list with plot , so you can use it more than one times if wont to add additional plot

Comment: here you create doc -- you need it only one time per file `if (type=="PPT") {doc = pptx();doc = addSlide(doc, slide.layout = "Blank");pagesize = dim(doc)$slide.dim} else {doc = docx();pagesize = dim(doc)$page-dim(doc)$margins[c(4,3)]}    
  pageaspectr = pagesize["width"]/pagesize["height"]`

Comment: I saw that but thought that reusing the function export2ppt(file="plot.pptx") a second time will add a new slide. Instead, it overrides the first pptx created with one new with one new graph inside.

Comment: yes because in your function you create doc every time. so you need to edit fucntion or use it like `doc=pptx()` then `addSlide()`+`addPlot()` for each your plot and at end `writeDoc()`

Comment: The answer below is outdated, as ReporteRs has been removed from CRAN and is superseded by officer. I just made a new package export built on top of officer that easily allows one to export several graphs to a single Powerpoint presentation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try for example

```
library(ReporteRs)
doc =pptx( ) # create pptx
doc=addSlide(doc,"Title and Content") # add slide
doc<-addTitle(doc,"first") # add title
fun_1<-function(){
  plot(mpg ~ wt,  data = mtcars)
}
doc <- addPlot(doc, fun= fun_1,vector.graphic =FALSE )  # add plot

doc=addSlide(doc,"Title and Content") # add slide
doc<-addTitle(doc,"Second") # add title

fun_2<-function(){
  plot(mpg ~ cyl,  data = mtcars)
}
doc <- addPlot(doc, fun= fun_2,vector.graphic =FALSE ) # add plot
writeDoc(doc, "r-2.pptx" )
```

Comment: I had to install from github because I couldn't find it on CRAN. However, when I am trying to use the code, I got this warning/error: `Please consider using package officer instead of package ReporteRs. Java <= 1.8 is needed for this package but not available` and `Function pptx is deprecated, please use officer::read_pptx() instead.Error in pptx() :  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException`

Answer (score 2):

The answer below is outdated, as `ReporteRs` has been removed from CRAN and is superseded by `officer`. I just made a new package `export` built on top of `officer` that easily allows one to export several graphs to a single Powerpoint presentation using the `graph2ppt()` command and the `append=TRUE` option, e.g. to produce a presentation with 2 slides :

```
install.packages("export")
library(export)
library(ggplot2)
qplot(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length, data = iris, color = Species, 
      size = Petal.Width, alpha = I(0.7))     
graph2ppt(file="plots.pptx", width=6, height=5) 
qplot(Sepal.Width, Petal.Length, data = iris, color = Species, 
      size = Petal.Width, alpha = I(0.7))     
graph2ppt(file="plots.pptx", width=6, height=5, append=TRUE)
```

Comment: Getting error : Error in add_slide(doc, layout = "Blank", master = "Office Theme") : 
  could not find layout named "Blank" in master named "Office Theme"

Answer (score 1):

eoffice may be another choice. with the command below:

```
install.packages("eoffice")
topptx(file="plots.pptx", width=6, height=5,append=T)
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to give an updated example using the `officer` package. You can batch create multiple slides of plots from a list of plots.  Here is a working example that saves an output.pptx to your working directory.

```
#Load packages
library(officer)
library(ggplot2)

#Here is an example list of plots
plot_list<- list()
plot_list[[1]] <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=hp, y=mpg)) + geom_point()
plot_list[[2]] <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=factor(gear))) + geom_bar()
plot_list[[3]] <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=factor(cyl), y=mpg)) + geom_boxplot()

# Create temporary .pptx file
file <- tempfile(fileext = ".pptx")

#Create a blank pptx object
pptx <- read_pptx()

#add slides to the pptx object in a loop
for(i in 1:length(plot_list)){
  pptx <- add_slide(pptx)
  pptx <- ph_with(pptx,
                  value = plot_list[[i]],
                  location = ph_location_fullsize() )
  
}
#print ("save") the pptx object to the tempfile
print(pptx, file)

#move the tempfile to current directory from the tempfile location.
destination_file <- file.path(getwd(), "output.pptx")
file.rename(file, destination_file)
```